# How can I link these MYSQL tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, create-table

I've been racking my brain trying to figure out how to accomplish a link through foreign keys to help make life easier. I have two tables set up and want to make a 3rd linking to them both adding a couple columns to the 3rd one. here's the syntax I came up with...

### [SQL Fiddle (with sample data)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8ccd2)

**Shirts**

```
CREATE TABLE shirts(
    shirt_id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    shirt_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    shirt_type VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    shirt_size VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    qp_price_id VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    o_price_id VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
)ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Tthere will be more with the V-Necks, Raglan Sleeve, Cap Sleeve etc. shirts....

**Price List**

```
CREATE TABLE price_list(
    price_id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    price_cat VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    price NUMERIC(6,2) NOT NULL
)ENGINE=INNODB
```

what I would like to do is create a 3rd table that selects the shirt_name, shirt_type, and shirt_size columns from from the shirts table then create two columns, one being qp_price and the other o_price and make those foreign keys to the price list table to grab the price for that shirt... and I figured maybe using a WHERE clause somehow where the price that shows is controlled by

```
WHERE shirts.qp_price_id=price_list.price_cat AND shirts.o_price_id=price_list.price_cat
```

I want to do it this way so I can make price changes as easily as possible to multiple items.  This chunk is just for each variety of crewneck shirts I need to represent... there's more...  all the crewneck shirts cost the same price from New Born- 1X adult, so I have those attributed to "crn-qp-a" and "crn-o-a" so if I can just change the price value of "crn-qp-a" ONE TIME and have it automatically update to 20 instances so I don't have to do it 20 times.... does this make sense?.... please help... lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to, first, remove price information from `shirts` table and keep it `price_list`, and then create the third table, and in it you can can link shirts to prices by `shirt_id` and `price_id`

```
create table shirt_price (
  shirt_id int UNSIGNED not null,
  qp_price_id int UNSIGNED not null,
  o_price_id int UNSIGNED not null,
  primary key (shirt_id, price_id),
  CONSTRAINT shirt_price_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (shirt_id) REFERENCES shirts (shirt_id),
  CONSTRAINT shirt_price_ibfk_2 FOREIGN KEY (qp_price_id) REFERENCES price_list (price_id),
  CONSTRAINT shirt_price_ibfk_3 FOREIGN KEY (o_price_id) REFERENCES price_list (price_id)   
)ENGINE=INNODB;
```

So for example, if your `shirts` table has the following shirts:

```
SHIRT_ID    SHIRT_NAME      SHIRT_TYPE  SHIRT_SIZE  
1           Crewneck Tee    Men         S
2           Crewneck Tee    Men         M
3           Crewneck Tee    Men         L
4           Crewneck Tee    Men         1X
5           Crewneck Tee    Men         2X
```

and your `price_list` table has the following prices:

```
PRICE_ID    PRICE_CAT   PRICE
1           crn_qp_a    27.2
2           crn_o_a     25.31
3           crn_qp_b    28.1
```

Then each shirt will link to 2 prices, one for the `qp` price, and the other for the `o` price.

```
SHIRT_ID    QP_PRICE_ID   O_PRICE_ID
1           1             2
2           1             2
3           1             2
4           3             2          
5           1             2
```

To query the price of all men shirts, you do the following:

```
select s.shirt_name, s.shirt_type, s.shirt_size, p_qp.price, p_o.price
from shirts s,
   price_list p_qp,
   price_list p_o,
   shirt_price rel
where s.shirt_type = 'Men'
  and rel.shirt_id = s.shirt_id
  and rel.qp_price_id = p_qp.price_id
  and rel.o_price_id = p_o.price_id;
```

**Useful Reading:**

- [mysql Joins](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqljoins.php)

Comment: Ok I just did this and created the 3rd table successfully.. but there's not values showing up in the table... and I see how it works in the example above, but I want all the info from the tables to show up in the 3rd table, just with the prices added..

Comment: you need to insert the values in the third table yourselves, for my example above, this is the `insert` used: `insert into shirt_price values (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 2), (5, 3);`

Comment: ok... I just did that.. and it linked them... but how do I make it where I can see the name, type, size price etc?

Comment: you can add those to the select statement columns `select s.shirt_name, s.shirt_type, s.shirt_size, p.price
from shirts s,
   price_list p,
   shirt_price rel
where s.shirt_type = 'Men'
  and rel.shirt_id = s.shirt_id
  and rel.price_id = p.price_id;` If you are new to joins, I also added a reference at the end of the answer, hope this helps!

Comment: oooh ok sorry... for some reason your posts aren't posting in full... I didn't see the end of your last response before... thanks for the info, let me play with it n see how it works..

Comment: ok I see how that works... but I need two price columns for each shirt, otherwise I'll have to double the shirts and have 66 of them.. which is why I tried the first way by making those reference names such as "crn_qp_a" and "crn_o_a" because those are two prices set for two purposes... let me explain more about what I'm trying to do...

Comment: I design custom tees, with the "qp" option they get that shirt with a design of their choice to be customized for them.  With the "o" option they get to have it customized from scratch, which will send the price off to another section where it will be subject to more prices.  So I want to make the table where  I can pull the prices of both off of it for either option the customer navigates to... make sense?

Comment: To achieve that, you have the relation table (i.e. 3rd table) link to two price types, which will actually be two references to the same `price_list` table. See the updated script. The relation table (i.e. `shirt_price`) has 3 columns now, one links to the `shirts` table and 2 link to the `price_list` table, but one for `qb price` and the other for the `o price`. Also note the updated `select statement`; it, now, joins the relation table with two aliases of the price_list table, to get both prices.

Comment: One final note, if one tee has only one option (qp or o, but not both), then rewrite the query using a `left outer join` to get the other option.